# Localization strings not shown properly

Tags: android, localization

I have an app we need to translate to several languages. So, I made values-en, values-pt, etc. One of the languages is turkish. So, I made my folder values-tr, and inside that, strings.xml file. Everything goes ok, except for one particular Activity. The strings that appear there are the ones in spanish (the default language in our app). BUT, if I change to another language (say, russian) and back to turkish, the strings are shown ok.

```
TextView mTitle = toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.mapproviders));
```

(In the strings.xml in values-tr):
     `<string name="mapproviders">Tedarikçi Haritası</string>`

It works ok for other languages, it only fails in turkish and in that particular Activity.

Anyone has faced a similar problem?

UPDATE:

This is the way I am changing Locale:

```
public static void changeLang(String lang, Context ctx) {
    Configuration config = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
        conf.locale = locale;
        ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the Locale setting in your app. Please check your locale setting for multiple languages - You can debug the current language before setting the String into the TextView.

Comment: It is a trouble with the locale, yes, I did what you suggested and locale was changed. It is not happening in any other place of the app. In the Activity that is failing there is a WebView that loads an URL, and I think it has something to do with that, that the webpage loaded somehow is messing with the locale of the app...

Comment: Ok. How you are changing the local? it must be via application base class context, So that it will be valid through out the app. Please try.

Comment: I am updating question with the way I am changing Locale.

Comment: Hi, Did you Find Any Solution With Turkish Locale Please Guide me